# Display hostname in GDM3 on Fedora 19 at login screen

Tags: fedora, gnome, login, hostname, gdm3

I'm managing almost 100 lab PC's running Fedora 19. It's difficult to manage because it seems like no where that I can display the hostname at the login screen.

GDM version: gdm-3.8-3.2

Comment: You have to edit the .bashrc file. What is the output you get when you run the command echo $PS1?

Comment: Assuming you're using graphical logins, you should be able to configure the [display manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Manager) to show information about the host. Which DM are you using?

Comment: What login screen? Text or GUI? You can display anything you like on either but you need to tell us how you are connecting to these machines and where you would like to see the hostname.

Comment: Hi Herman. Its gdm-3.8-3.2

Comment: Have you checked the files under `/etc/gdm3`? There should be a `greeter.conf` there.

Comment: In my Fedora 19 there is no directory /etc/gdm3

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
cat > /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/01-mysettings <<EOF
[org/gnome/login-screen]
banner-message-enable=true
banner-message-text='<PUT HOSTNAME HERE>' 
disable-restart-buttons=false
disable-user-list=false
EOF

rm /etc/dconf/db/gdm
dconf update
```

Comment: I need a solution that can be applied for 100 lab PC. So by putting that hostname like this is very ugly

Also, I disable user list, so virtually the banner message doesnt display at all. I dont know why